# Why is it that if an eigenvalue of a $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrix is 1 then the dimension of the eigenspace is 3?

Tags: linear-algebra

Basically the title

Why is it that if an eigenvalue of a $3 \times 3$ orthogonal matrix is 1 then the dimension of the eigenspace is 3?

I can also add that I know that the dimension of the eigenspace is equal to the number of basis of the null space.

Comment: It doesn't have to be, what about a rotation through some $\theta \notin \pi \mathbb{Z}$ about the $z$-axis?

Comment: @NoahOlander Thanks to both of you, would you mind elaborating a bit more your answer I am very new to eigenspaces.

Comment: Well if the dimension of the eigenspace associated with $1$ were $3$, then the eigenspace would be all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, so that we would have $A=I_3$ for any orthogonal matrix with $1$ as an eigenvalue. However, this is false - the rotation I mentioned is orthogonal (you should try to write down its matrix) and since $\theta \notin \pi \mathbb{Z}$ it's not the identity. It has one as an eigenvalue because it fixes $e_3$.

Comment: Thank you @NoahOlander where can I read up on the fact that if the dimension of the eigenspace associated with $1$ were $3$, then the eigenspace would be all of $R^3$, so that we would have $A=I_3$ for any orthogonal matrix with $1$ as an eigenvalue? I will study the proof so then I can understand what is going on :) .

Comment: No problem! You can find it in any linear algebra textbook. You just need to know that the only subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which has dimension $3$ is $\mathbb{R}^3$ itself. Therefore, the eigenspace associated with $1$ is all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Now just use the definition of eigenspace to figure out what this tells you about $A$.